# "ECONNRESET" error in node mysql application

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

This error comming from my hosted node mysql application.
It's wokrs fine in my local computer

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/ufkgmlcg/nodevenv/happyface_social/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/home/ufkgmlcg/nodevenv/happyface_social/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/home/ufkgmlcg/nodevenv/happyface_social/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:371:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (/home/ufkgmlcg/nodevenv/happyface_social/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
}
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of where you are hosting the application, and the code snippet used to connect to mysql its hard to tell.

But, most probably in your code where you are connecting to mysql you have added the path to your localhost running mysql while when you are hosting the application the path to mysql database is different.

To solve the issue, you should read how to connect to mysql on the platform you are hosting the application and then use environment variables to connect to it.

You will specify your local database path in your computer while the hosted db path in the hosting platform using environment variables.

Comment: I'm using cpanel for this. And environment variables are ok. I checked the all code. No any issue with db connection.

Comment: And the application is working. I can see data from the dataabse. But it's auto restarting. I think the reason is the above error

Comment: I run new program to connect to the database And I can see same error

Comment: can you add the code snippet you are using to connect with the database, and is it just happening in hosted application ?

Comment: it's down there

Answer (score 0):

connection

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        port: 3306
    });
```

index

```
db.connect((error) => error ? console.log(error) : console.log("MysqlDB connected..!"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).